# VB.NET runs differently when message box removed - Outlook Application

Tags: vb.net, outlook-addin, mailitem, outlook.application

I'm currently developing an Outlook Application, which seemed to work perfectly during testing.

This code seems to work when the `MSGBox("ASDFG")` is in place (`rsts.Count` returns `1`), but as soon as it is removed, the statement returns `0`. I have tried to surpass this by adding `Debug.Print`'s to see if that made any difference, but I still find that the code will only run correctly when the `MSGBox` is in place.

I even added a `Timer1` interval to re-run the script every second if it returns 0.

```
Function myThread()
    Dim oApp As Outlook.Application = CreateObject("Outlook.application")
    Dim sch As Outlook.Search
    Dim rsts As Outlook.Results
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim myTaskSearch As String = ToolStripStatusLabel2.Text
    Dim strF As String = "urn:schemas:mailheader:subject LIKE '%Task: " & myTaskSearch & "%'"
    Const strS As String = "Inbox"

    Try
        sch = oApp.AdvancedSearch(strS, strF)
        rsts = sch.Results
        MsgBox("ASDFG")
        Debug.Print(sch.Results.ToString)
        Debug.Print("'" & myTaskSearch & "'")

        If rsts.Count = 0 Then
            Debug.Print(rsts.Count)
            Timer1.Interval = 1000
            Timer1.Start()
        End If
        For i = 1 To rsts.Count
            Debug.Print(i)
            Timer1.Stop()
            TabControl1.TabPages.Add(i)
            'rsts.Item(i).Body
            'rsts.Item(i).SenderName
        Next
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Function

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    myThread()
End Sub
```

---

With MSGBox

[image: With MSGBox]

---

Without MSGBox + Debug

[image: Without MSGBox]

Comment: The search is [asynchronous](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch#example). Your `MsgBox` gives it time to complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event handler to be called when the search is complete. As GSerg said, AdvancedSearch is asynchronous so it is still running when your code prints the count.

See [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.advancedsearch) for a code example.

Comment: Spot on, while the `Application_AdvancedSearchComplete` sub didn't seem to work from the documentation, I managed to get a `while < 1` loop working.